# Search with parameter products from a table in r

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to create a function `search(atr, spec, products)` to search with certain parameters from a table like this:

```
    Zoom    Size    Resolution 
1    12     98      3200
2    15     100     3500
3    10     120     3100
4    8      90      2500
```

Where if the attribute (`atr`) exists then it should show which product(s) have at least the specification written (`spec`).

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
my_search = function(atr, spec, products) {
  #1 products = data.frame?
  if(is.data.frame(products)) {
    #2 does atr exist in products?
    if(atr %in% names(products)) {
      result = products[which(products$spec>=spec),]
      return(result)
    } else {
      print("Sorry, there is no product with that attribute")
    }
  } else {
    print("Sorry, the variable products has to be a data frame")
  }
}
```

Comment: what doesn't work? error messages?

Comment: I tried it with the example `search("Zoom", 27, cameras)` and got the result: [1] Resolution  Zoom        Size        Price       Screen      Video       Settings    Sensitivity
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: Your function is called `my_search` so why are you calling `search(...)`?

Comment: Sorry, I called `my_search("Zoom", 27, cameras)`

Comment: `products$spec` will always try and get a column called `spec`, not the value of a variable named `spec`. Use `products[[spec]]` to get a column with the name of the value of `spec`. That could be your problem.

Comment: I tried but now I get the following message: Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Do you really want `products[[atr]] >= spec`?

Comment: That was exactly the mistake :)

Comment: Insert a `browser` at the beginning of the function and step through it, one line at a time, inspecting what is going on.